# Inconsistent data type error: expected Date got Number

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
create table reserves(
  day date,
  sid INT,
  bid INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(sid) REFERENCES sailors(sid),
  FOREIGN KEY(bid) REFERENCES boats(bid)
);

insert into reserves values(&sid,&bid,'&date');
SQL> INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (&sid, &bid, TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'));
Enter value for sid: 22
Enter value for bid: 103
Enter value for date: 10/10/98
old   1: INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (&sid, &bid, TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'))
new   1: INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (22, 103, TO_DATE('10/10/98', 'MM/DD/YY'))
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (22, 103, TO_DATE('10/10/98', 'MM/DD/YY'))
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

Need to insert values of date, but can't. Can anyone explain what is the reason

Comment: Are you aware of the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to explicitly include the identifiers for the columns you are inserting into and then you can put the values into whatever order you want:

```sql
INSERT INTO reserves (sid, bid, day) VALUES (&sid, &bid, TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'));
```

the other alternative (which is not considered best practice) is to include the columns in the same order that they were defined in the table (as the 1<sup>st</sup> column is `day`, not the 3<sup>rd</sup>):

```sql
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'), &sid, &bid);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `insert` statement you have to either keep the order of columns from `create table` statement

```sql
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES (TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'), &sid, &bid);
```

or explicitly provide the order in insert statement

```sql
INSERT INTO reserves (sid, bid, day) VALUES (&sid, &bid, TO_DATE('&date', 'MM/DD/YY'));
```